# Merging two methods of creating bibliography

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I have two format of bibliography.
First

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1}



 \bibitem{notes} John W. Dower {\em Readings compiled for History
  21.479.}  1991.

  \bibitem{fo} Bob Tadashi Wakabayashi {\em Anti-Foreignism and Western
  Learning in Early-Modern Japan} 1986: Harvard University Press.

  \end{thebibliography}
```

and second, I have some bib file and I have the following command in my
 file:

```
\bibliographystyle{amsplain}
\bibliography{file1,file2}
```

How do I merge these two formats into a single list of references. I know that I can make a bibfile of the documents in   "\begin{thebibliography}{1}" by adding entry by entry. But my actual list of files is large and I do not want to give my time to make a bib file entry by entry.

Is there a fast way to merge these two styles and bring them under a common list of references?

Comment: If you want the sources re-sorted and merged into one list converting your `thebibliography` list to a `.bib` file is by far the easiest way. You should be able to convert the whole list with just some simple edits, no need to write entries one at a time

Comment: I could not understand it. Can you please explain how to convert the list in "thebibliography" to a .bib file with simple edits?

Comment: it depends how regular your list is but for a start  replace `\\bibitem{[^{}]*)}(.*{\\em` by `@ARTICLE{$1,`  and then just iterate with replace expressions until your list is valid bibtex, probably takes a few minutes of fiddling and then hand correction of any reaming odd entries that don't fit a pattern.